# What is wrong? "Error: INSERT INTO.... Unknown column 'jon' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to input a form into my database, but there are two different errors showing

```
"Error: INSERT INTO movie (firstname, surname, phonenumber, email, movie, session, day) values(jon, doe, johndoe@icloud.com, 123456789, halloween, afternoon, tuesday)You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@icloud.com, 123456789, halloween, afternoon, tuesday)' at line 3"
```

i tried removin the "@" sign but instead this came up:

```
"Error: INSERT INTO movie (firstname, surname, phonenumber, email, 
movie, session, day) values(jon, doe, johndoeicloud.com, 123456789, 
halloween, afternoon, tuesday)Unknown column 'jon' in 'field list'"
```

This is my code

```
if (!empty($firstname) || !empty($surname) || !empty($email) || !empty($phonenumber) || !empty($Localmovie) || !empty($session) || !empty($day)) {
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbUsername= "root";
        $dbPassword="";
        $dbName="tickets";

        //create connection
        $conn= new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect 
Error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{


             //$sql = "INSERT INTO tutorials_inf(name)VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."')";
            $sql= "INSERT INTO movie
                        (firstname, surname, phonenumber, email, movie, session, day) 
                   values($firstname, $surname, $email, 
$phonenumber, $Localmovie, $session, $day)";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
               echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
               echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            $conn->close();
```

im using phpmyadmin through xampp on macOS Mojave

Comment: Looks like you need quotes around the values, They are being interpreted as column names, not strings.

Comment: You are also WIDE open to a [sql injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should definitely not use this on any public facing server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **single quotes** to your value for string representation and also properly re-arrange the **values** based on your **columns**(You miss-places `phonenumber` and `email` column-value sequence)

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO movie (firstname, surname, phonenumber, email, movie, session, day) values($firstname, $surname, $email, $phonenumber, $Localmovie, $session, $day)";
```

To

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO movie (firstname, surname, phonenumber, email, movie, session, day) values('$firstname', '$surname', '$phonenumber', '$email','$Localmovie', '$session', '$day')";
```

- The **date** and **string** values should be enclosed in **single quotes**.
- The **numeric** values do not need to be enclosed in quotes.